# Piping output from 1 command to other command in an adb shell command line

Tags: android, shell, pipe, adb

I wish to send an adb shell command to an Android device that pipes output from 1 command to other command, but when I try to do that, only the 1st command is executed on the device, and the 2nd one is executed on the host machine. Here's what I tried:

```
adb shell command1 | command2
```

command1 is executed on the device, and command2 on the host machine.

How can I get this to work properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
adb shell "command1 | command2"
```

Comment: I'll try that. What if command1 includes quotation marks of its own? For example, echo "123"? would it throw adb off?

Comment: you will need to escape those or use a combination of single and double quotation marks

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a shell script containing the commands you want and then run the shell script.

Since the Android root filesystem is not writeable at run time (usually, unless you have rooted your device and remount it), you can copy the file to the removable (or emulated) storage, for example `/sdcard`.

Then run the script using the command `adb shell sh /sdcard/your-script-name`. Because each script runs in its own subshell, both of your commands will be executed in the same shell on the device (you can confirm it with `ps`).

Comment: That was my initial idea, but I thought there might be a way of getting around it.

Answer (score 0):

```
adb shell "command1 && command2"
```

example:

Recursive listing of all files under /system/lib that contain 'foo':

```
adb shell "cd /system/lib&&ls -lR .|grep -i foo"
```

The important thing is the double quotes and the double ampersand.

The only thing is that you cannot use it for input as well, meaning that running an executable that requires stdin using one-liner wouldn't work as it requires user intervention.